# What are DOS programs written in?

Tags: windows, dos

I've always been curious... What programming language are DOS programs written in? For example, this program: http://keyhut.com/pos.htm

You can use the arrows on the keyboard to select options, type in things, press enter to do things...

At my work, all of our backend looks like DOS, the blue screen, you use the arrows on keyboard to select options... etc.

How could I create an interactive DOS program like that?

Comment: There are various CLI "window" libraries available. Generally they are designed to work with an "ANSI VT" IIRC (the border use "||" and "|-" characters and whatnot from the [DOS codepage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)). I believe there was one from Allegro ... ? As far as the language: much of it is C, but it's not exclusively so.

Comment: QuickBasic was the ideal language for writing games involving gorillas chucking bananas..

Comment: @MikeChristensen Ahh, and Nibbles (which *does* use the DOS codepage to simulate the graphics). The gorillas switched to graphics mode. Forgot about those ;-)

Comment: TurboPascal and TurboC from Borland had a nice Library called TurboVision to crate nice text guis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were many languages out there for those sort of apps.

They include QBasic, Turbo Pascal, Turbo C++.

Here is a helpful page to get started : http://www.opus.co.tt/dave/program.htm. You may also want to google to find the language you're interested in.